# Buildroot not compiling

Tags: buildroot

every time I run `make`

it starts compiling but then stops and tells me this:

````
tmp-divrem_1.s:130: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:146: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:159: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:176: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r3,r8' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:210: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r11,r4,r12,r3' in ARM mode
make[3]: *** [Makefile:768: divrem_1.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libtool: compile:  /usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib2_ui -I/home/pi/buildroot/output/host/include -O2 -I/home/pi/buildroot/output/host/include -c fib2_ui.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fib2_ui.o
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1/mpn'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:997: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:787: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1'
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:250: /home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1/.stamp_built] Error 2```
````

Comment: This looks like a toolchain/target configuration issue. Could you tell us what host you use, what the host toolchain is (version, architecture, ...), what the target is as well as which toolchain you use? You can also post your `.config` file so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @SimonDoppler, I used a raspberry pi4 4GB, I don't understand everything else.

Comment: There should be a `.config` file in your buildroot directory, could you share this? It contains all the information required to build your project.

Comment: @SimonDoppler, Sure!
[Download .config](https://snorain.000webhostapp.com/main/upload/uploaded/.config)

Comment: Do you build on a raspberry pi? (which one? and what os version?) What is the board you are building for? Also the raspberry? (for the config, it may take a day or two to debug, I don't have a RPi at hand right now)

Comment: @SimonDoppler, Yes i did build on raspberry pi, raspberry pi 4 4GB, OS: Raspberry pi Desktop simple.

Comment: What board are you compiling for? I couldn't find the board information in the .config file.

Comment: @SimonDoppler Raspberry pi 4

Comment: Then it is definitely a setup error (your target architecture is i586 in the config, but the Raspberry have ARM CPUs). If you haven't already, I would start from the default raspberry pi configuration and work from there. You can achieve this with `make clean` to go back to a clean state and then `make raspberrypi4_defconfig` to set the configuration to RPi 4. Then you can run `make` to build.

Comment: @SimonDoppler After running all of that i get this:
make[3]: *** [Makefile:768: divrem_1.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libtool: compile:  /usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_divrem_2 -I/home/pi/buildroot/output/host/include -O2 -I/home/pi/buildroot/output/host/include -c divrem_2.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/divrem_2.o

Comment: make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1/mpn'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:997: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:787: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1'
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:250: /home/pi/buildroot/output/build/host-gmp-6.2.1/.stamp_built] Error 2

Comment: Can you post the compiler error message (above the line with `make[3]`)?

Answer (score 0):

From the config it looks like you're compiling for i586, not arm or aarch64.

If you type `make list-defconfigs`, then it will show you a list; here's an excerpt:

```
raspberrypi2_defconfig              - Build for raspberrypi2
raspberrypi4_64_defconfig           - Build for raspberrypi4_64
raspberrypi4_defconfig              - Build for raspberrypi4
sheevaplug_defconfig                - Build for sheevaplug
```

Once you have identified the defconfig you need, then you can do this:

```
make raspberrypi4_defconfig
```

and it'll initialize a basic configuration for the selected target. With this configuration, your compilation should run to completion.